# Gap between elements and wrapping not consistent

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-flex-layout

I have a page where the left and right are split evenly. On the right side, I have a bunch of `div` elements containing an `img` and a `span`. What I'm trying to do is show four of these `div` elements at MOST per row, and start to wrap on smaller screens, with a specific gap.

The problem I'm having is the gap is wider on bigger screens, and the elements squish together on smaller screens instead of wrapping, regardless of what gap value I set.

Here's a gif showing what's happening: https://gfycat.com/remorsefulglossyherring

Here's the relevant HTML (only the right side of the page which contains these divs):

```
<div
  class="about"
  fxFlex="50%"
  fxLayout="row wrap"
  fxLayoutGap="10px grid"
  fxLayoutAlign="center center"
>
  <div fxFlex="25%" class="item">
    <img class="img-skills" src="assets/c-sharp.png" alt="C#" />
    <span class="caption">C#</span>
  </div>
  <div fxFlex="25%" class="item">
    <img class="img-skills" src="assets/.net-core.png" alt=".NET Core" />
    <span class="caption">.NET Core</span>
  </div>
  <div fxFlex="25%" class="item">
    <img class="img-skills" src="assets/wpf.png" alt="WPF" />
    <span class="caption">WPF</span>
  </div>
  <div fxFlex="25%" class="item">
    <img class="img-skills" src="assets/winforms.jpg" alt="WinForms" />
    <span class="caption">WinForms</span>
  </div>
  <div fxFlex="25%" class="item">
    <img class="img-skills" src="assets/angular.png" alt="Angular" />
    <span class="caption">Angular</span>
  </div>
  <div fxFlex="25%" class="item">
    <img class="img-skills" src="assets/nodejs.png" alt="NodeJS" />
    <span class="caption">Node.js</span>
  </div>
  <div fxFlex="25%" class="item">
    <img class="img-skills" src="assets/html5.png" alt="HTML5" />
    <span class="caption">HTML5</span>
  </div>
  <div fxFlex="25%" class="item">
    <img class="img-skills" src="assets/css3.png" alt="CSS3" />
    <span class="caption">CSS3</span>
  </div>
  <div fxFlex="25%" class="item">
    <img class="img-skills" src="assets/mongodb.png" alt="MongoDB" />
    <span class="caption">MongoDB</span>
  </div>
  <div fxFlex="25%" class="item">
    <img
      class="img-skills"
      src="assets/mssql.png"
      alt="Microsoft SQL Server"
    />
    <span class="caption">Microsoft SQL Server</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's the css:

```
.about {
  min-height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
}

div.item {
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 120px;
}

.img-skills {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: grey;
}

.caption {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: Fortunately your code is working as expected! it wraps into single column when you decrease the width: https://jsfiddle.net/Manju06/eg37c6nj/1/ so what is you want?

Comment: If you take a look at the .gif, they get squished together instead of wrapping to the next line.

Comment: @OP I got that in GIF, but the code you shared working as expected is what I meant.

Comment: So do you know how I change it to achieve what I want? I want a gap that is always the same between the divs, and when that gap can't be achieved with the current screen size, it should wrap the next element to the next row. Yes it should work like your jsfiddle example, but max 4 items per row.

Comment: I suggest you to have a div which contain 4 icons and make it as flex, it by default wrap automatically with no extra codes.

Comment: Okay I see what you mean. I thought there might be a way to do it without creating a div for every 4 icons.

Comment: Reason behind saying div because as you said you need 4 icons in first row and other 4 icons in second row, which made me to say use div, if you don't have the constraint of number of icons in the row then that div won't be required, it can be done easily by flex. OR you can make a width which can accommodate 4 icons in the row and it automatically move other 4 items to next line making it as 2 rows with 4 icons each and without saying it goes that it easily wrap to a single column.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try setting a fixed width, that seems like a good idea.

Comment: I have just posted an example of what I mean, I have even added fiddle so that you can play around with the size, so you just have to concentrate on the `flex` which is used in parent div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the simple idea, but this will help you for sure to start with:

Play around here : [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Manju06/xkngvf7t/3/)

```css
.MainDiv {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.first {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: gray;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="MainDiv">
  <div class="first"></div>
  <div class="first"></div>
  <div class="first"></div>
  <div class="first"></div>
  <div class="first"></div>
  <div class="first"></div>
  <div class="first"></div>
  <div class="first"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make it both left and right divs separated with the main container.

Your right side div should be like this below.

```
 <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutGap="20px">
     <div>1. One</div> 
     <div>2. Two</div> 
      <div>3. Three</div> 
      <div>4. Four</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That just makes all the divs into one row. I'm trying to 4 per row at most, and as the screen shrinks it'll wrap them onto the next row.